# x509 CheckSignature parameter

Tags: go, cryptography, digital-signature, x509

In the x509 library, there is a function called `CheckSignature`. I'm a bit lost as to what to pass into `signed`. What is it supposed to be?

The function is

```
func (c *Certificate) CheckSignature(algo SignatureAlgorithm, signed, signature []byte) (err error)
```

https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/x509.go?s=21660:21759#L623

Another thing I want to double is that if I signed something with the private key associated with the certificate, will that signature pass this `CheckSignature` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`signed` looks to be the certificate in ASN.1 DER format of the *signer*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the parent certificate to check the signature on the issued certificate. eg:

```
// parent is the parent x509.Certificate
// cert is the certificate signed by the parent
// alg is the algorithm used to sign, eg x509.PureEd25519
alg := cert.SignatureAlgorithm
err := parent.CheckSignature(alg, cert.RawTBSCertificate, cert.Signature)
if err != nil {
    return errors.New("Signature invalid")
}
```